# tinymce stand alone version suddenly not working

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

A while back I downloaded the tinymce Developer Package 4.6.6 from https://www.tinymce.com/download/.  I installed it, configured it and it worked like a dream (with a bit of tinkering).  All of a sudden, it has stopped working. I can still enter text into the textarea, but I am unable to format it AT ALL.  When I submit the Form and dump the content of the textarea, there is nothing there.  I didn't change any code, so I am wondering if I have breached some sort of Licence limit. Has anyone got any ideas?  The Code is dead simple:

JS:

```
<script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({ 
selector:'textarea.theme1',
branding: false,
statusbar: false,
menubar : false,
height: 500,
plugins: 'table,lists,fullscreen,textcolor',
table_default_styles: { width: '90%' },
toolbar: 'table,lists,fullscreen,textcolor',
toolbar1: 'undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect',
toolbar2: 'bold italic underline forecolor',
toolbar3: 'alignleft alignright aligncenter indent outdent bullist numlist',
toolbar4: 'table | fullscreen '
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="theme1" name="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's JavaScript console when you try to use the local install of TinyMCE?

Comment: Thanks Michael - I left it alone for 8 hours and it now works again (I'm sure I didn't change any code, but maybe I did).  Can only assume it was a caching issue of some kind (on multiple browsers, may I add).  Thanks for the Console tip - I am using it on IE and am finding some other minor issues to tidy up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgot to add:
if I replace the local js file:

```
<script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

with the Cloud js file:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

it works again.

Go figure.